# Why wasn't there any international outrage on the Hindu genocide carried out by Pakistan during 1971?

Tags: genocide, pakistan, united-nations, human-rights

It was an ethnic cleansing deliberately carried out by the Pakistani troops to get rid of the Hindu minority communities especially Bengali population that mostly settled in eastern Pakistan post partition. It's estimated that up to 3 million were wiped out and an even greater number sought refuge in India.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1971_Bangladesh_genocide

**Why wasn't there any international outrage on the Hindu genocide carried out by Pakistan during 1971?**

Comment: Doesn't the "[International reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1971_Bangladesh_genocide#International_reactions)" section of the linked wikipedia article answer the question?